# How do I declare a private String without an error?

Tags: java

```
  public class Seat {

    private int no;
    private String class;
    private boolean pos;
    private boolean table;
    private boolean dir;
    private boolean access;

    public Seat()
    {
    }
}
```

When I try to declare the String class I continue to get an error, I know it's probably something really simple.

Comment: `class` is a [keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9).

Comment: @TangledUpInBlue has got it going on. Check out their answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `class` as a variable name because it has a specific meaning in Java.  Choose a different variable name for your string.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the reserved keyword `class` to name your variable, which won't compile.

Use a non-reserved name for your `String` variable.

See variable naming rules [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), and reserved keywords [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).

The `class` keyword is used to declare classes, such as in your `Seat` class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

`class` is a reserved word of java try to rename with other name :

```
  private String someName;
```

Comment: downvoter some comment please for this -3

Comment: I'm not downvoter,however suggest the issue is in variable name `some_name`.Should be camel case like `someName`.And the second - answer duplicates other answers that was posted earlier.

Comment: It was probably downvoted when "some_name" was "some name" with a space.

Comment: @Abdelhak I didn't downvote; even if it was a typo, it was incorrect, even if you have since corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite most detected in all the previous answers:

according to the [Oracle web site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html):

> Here is a list of keywords in the Java programming language. You
>   cannot use any of the following as identifiers in your programs. The
>   keywords const and goto are reserved, even though they are not
>   currently used. true, false, and null might seem like keywords, but
>   they are actually literals; you cannot use them as identifiers in your
>   programs.

*abstract, continue, for, new, switch assert, default, goto, package, synchronized boolean, do, if, private, this break, double, implements, protected, throw byte, else, import, public, throws case, enum, instanceof, return, transient catch, extends, int, short, try char, final, interface, static, void class, finally, long, strictfp, volatile const, float, native, super, while*

---

So, declaring a variable with any of those names **will drive your compiler nuts**, and it will complain about the syntax of the code.