# How to test for null java Class<?>

Tags: java, class

I have a `HashMap<key, Class<?>>`  and am loading it with classes as shown below.

```
HashMap<Integer, Class<?>> classes = HashMap< Integer, Class<?>>();
classes.put(1, MyObject1.class);
classes.put(2, MyObject2.class);
classes.put(3, MyObject3.class);
```

Now I want to find the class for

```
Class<?> value = classes.get(keyValue)
```

And check if we found something for the keyValue

```
if (value != null) {
   // do something
   sendSomewhere(value);
}
```

But this crashes - seems `Class<?> != null` is not allows.  Is there any way of doing this ? see full snipped below.

```
private int[] screens = {1,2,3};
    public void setScreens(int[] screens){
        this.screens = screens;
    }
    int currentActivity = 0;

    HashMap<Integer, Class<?>> activities = new HashMap<Integer, Class<?>>();
    private void setActivities(){
        activities.put(1, QuestionnaireActivity_01.class);
        activities.put(2, QuestionnaireActivity_02.class);
        activities.put(3, QuestionnaireActivity_03.class);
        activities.put(4, QuestionnaireActivity_04.class);
        activities.put(5, QuestionnaireActivity_05.class);
    }
    // Find the next Activity in the screens array
    public Class<?> getNextActivity(){

        return getActivity();

    }
    private Class<?> getActivity(){

        if (currentActivity >= screens.length) {

            return UploadActivity.class;

        }
        int key = screens[currentActivity];
        Class<?> value = activities.get(key);
        currentActivity += 1;

        Logger.Log("Next Questionnaire: "+ value.toString());
        if (value.getName().length() > 0) {

            return value;

        } else {
            return getActivity();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634123/how-do-i-declare-a-private-string-without-an-error

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: No exception - app just gets terminated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has changed from a question about syntax to another question about syntax to the current version...

Answer (score 7):

**Edit**

This answer is valid for the first few edits of the question. 
The question has been edited drastically enough to make this answer seem off topic now.

---

Your code won't compile.

Declare your `Class<?>` variable with a legal variable name. `class` isn't one - it's a reserved keyword for declaring classes.

You could use `clazz`.

Secondly, on this idiom:

```
Class<?> value = HashMap.get(keyValue);
```

You are actually referencing the class `HashMap` instead of your map, and invoking a non-existing static method `get`, parametrized with some `keyValue` variable).

Use instead:

```
Class<?> value = classes.get(keyValue)
```

... where `classes` is the name of your `Map` variable.

Comment: Thanks, I use 'value' as the variable name - just corrected the question

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald see my edit.

Comment: My bad again - actually I am doing as you suggest, just my retyping of the question was wrong - see edited response with actual code snippet.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald you're never comparing any `Class<?>` to `null` in your large edit. Likely your code crashes at runtime for some other reason. I suggest you rollback your edit and ask a new question with the actual question you had in mind to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

`class` is [reserved keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html). Use e.g. `clazz` as variavle name instead:

```
Class<?> clazz = HashMap.get(keyValue)
```